# Deploying WAR on server somehow looses UTF-8 charset encoding?

Tags: java, linux, utf-8, character-encoding, raspbian

I kind of tested my application on my local tomcat server within eclipse, it was working all fine, however once I deployed the WAR of the application on a linux server (raspbian), it was replacing all non ASCII characters with question marks.

I believe I have 3 important points in my application where this can go wrong. it's reading files, writing to files and sending an email. I do get the impression however that reading and writing to files is not where it fails, as the output file contains all the characters correctly and while reading and writing I'm specifying UTF-8 as encoding to use, which were read from the input file, however the logs files and emails sent have question marks instead of non ascii characters, so my assumption would be that the system encoding is not UTF-8 and java uses it. How do I solve it? I can't find a way to find what encoding the linux system or how to change it.

The server for running the WAR is a Tomcat 7 server.

```
Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("user@service.com", "User"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipient));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setText(text);

            Transport.send(message);
```

Comment: Include the code that creates e-mails in your question.

Comment: @VGR added the code now, UTF-8 is not defined for the text and subject, but locally running it on Tomcat via Eclilpse there were no problems. I guess I have to change the default character encoding on linux, but how?

Comment: Does `message.setText(text, "UTF-8");` produce different results?

Comment: @VGR I tried, but there's no method setText with 2 parameters, you can only set one parameter

Comment: Change the type of `message` to be `MimeMessage`.  [setText(String, String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#setText-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) is unique to MimeMessage.

Comment: Aaaah, that's why I wasn't able to pass the argument... Thanks for that. Okay I changed now, do I also need to do the same for the subject? Also should it be "UTF-8" or "text/plain; charset=UTF-8"?? I've seen that as the suggested one, but it was for setContent method, so not sure if it would be good here. Is there a class defining the needed String constants?

Comment: I would use the two-argument `setSubject` method, yes.  The documentation states that the second argument for both setSubject and setText is a charset, not a MIME type, so it should just be `"UTF-8"`.